# Oracle %TYPE: when one var, two tables, how to define?

Tags: oracle, types, plsql, rowtype

Let's say I have two tables, payments_received and payments_processed. I want to declare a variable in PL/SQL to copy the data from one table to the other. Both tables have a field that holds the same value, say payor_name. Which table do I use to define the %TYPE, the "from" or the "to"?

```
PROCEDURE some_proc AS

  -- value coming FROM payments_received
  -- value going TO payments_processed

  v_payor_name  payments_received.payor_name%TYPE;
    -- OR
  v_payor_name  payments_processed.payor_name%TYPE;

BEGIN

  SELECT payor_name INTO v_payor_name
    FROM payments_received
   WHERE payment_id = some_payment_id;

  UPDATE payments_processed
     SET payor_name = v_payor_name
   WHERE processed_id = some_processed_id;

END some_proc;
```

I looked around for some best practice guidance, but didn't find anything that really seemed to cover this aspect of %TYPE/%ROWTYPE usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generally doesn't matter.  Presumably, the `payor_name` column is declared identically in the two tables.

Personally, I'd probably use the source table because that will be consistent if you need to select more than one column (or the entire row) now or in the future.  But I wouldn't object if someone wanted to use the destination table as the anchor type.

If there is some reason that it would be better to error out at the `SELECT` statement or at the `UPDATE` statement if there is some difference in the declarations, that might be lead you to prefer one over the other.  That's pretty uncommon, though, so it is generally a matter of preference and consistency.

Answer (score 1):

If someone wanted to be really strict about it, they could have both:

```
PROCEDURE some_proc AS

  -- value coming FROM payments_received
  -- value going TO payments_processed

  v_payor_name_source  payments_received.payor_name%TYPE;
  v_payor_name_target  payments_processed.payor_name%TYPE;

BEGIN

  SELECT payor_name INTO v_payor_name_source
    FROM payments_received
   WHERE payment_id = some_payment_id;

  v_payor_name_target := v_payor_name_source;

  UPDATE payments_processed
     SET payor_name = v_payor_name_target
   WHERE processed_id = some_processed_id;

END some_proc;
```

But I'd consider this overkill.